# Datetime is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

i have some trouble with an script part.

The part is this:

```
$datetime = date('d.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r', substr($row['expires'], 0, -3));
echo "<td>$datetime</td>";
```

The script result:

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/141208/swk8pe2s.jpg

The full script:

http://pastie.org/9767822

The problem:

Its the wrong time... its the 08.12.2014 not 11.12.2014
I dont know what is wrong, can anybody please help?

Comment: Nobody can tell unless you explain what `$row["expires"]` is, or why you mangle it.

Comment: What's the type of `expires` column in your database table? Could you give an example of a few typical values?

Comment: Then the answer given there is not working, so I'm marking it as dupe.

Comment: This is not an dupe, this is another question. The "expires" comes from an spigot plugin. For now i'm not on my computer...

Answer (score 0):

Can we see where $row is coming from? i.e. can you post some rows from your database?
My guess would be that the value passed from $row['expires'] is not what you are expecting, and hence causing $datetime to have an unexpected value.
Try the following:

```
$datetime = date('d.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r', strtotime(substr($row['expires'], 0, -3)));
```

If that still produces incorrect results, the time is probably being saved incorrectly in the first place (keep in mind that you might need to set the timezone for your script to use)

If you don't get it right with the code above, please post an example of a row that is being passed into $row so that we can see what the input is.  Your syntax looks pretty correct, so I would think the problem is the data that is being passed to the script.

Comment: Yes when i'm back i will write some rows here

Comment: Dont know if it helps, here are the site: This is the site http://www.balayacraft.de/banlist/warns.php

Comment: Ok i try this one, with this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /var/customers/webs/ni103312_3/banlist/warns.php on line 26

Comment: The row comes from an plugin. $row['name'] , $row ['banner'], $row['reason'] this comes all from the plugin.